# CURL variables and problems parsing JSON

Tags: bash, shell, curl, github-api

My script is creating pull requests using the github API:

`./my-script.sh my-repo my-branch`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

Repo=$1
Branch=$2

cd $Repo
 
get_data() {
cat <<EOF
    {
        "title": "PR title",
        "head": $Branch,
        "base": "development",
        "body": "PR description"
    }
EOF
}

echo $(get_data) # <----------------- I can see my value of the variable $Branch here

curl -X POST \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    -d "$(get_data)" \ # <----------------- But here I'm facing "Problems parsing JSON"
    -u my_user:my_token \
    https://api.github.com/repos/my_user/$Repo/pulls

open https://github.com/my_user/$Repo/pulls
```

How can I set my variable into the curl correctly?

Comment: Function get_data works as intended without the variable

Comment: Define the data with '?

`
get_data() {
cat <<EOF
    {
        'title': 'PR title',
        'head': '$Branch',
        'base': 'development',
        'body': 'PR description'
    }
EOF
}
`

Comment: @Dan_Maff You are right. "head": "$Branch", worked!

Comment: @Dan_Maff Feel free to add your answer. I hope my script will be useful for someone

Comment: Did the quotation marks in the data definition work @dmitry-grinko? I would have expected it to require apostrophes there.

Comment: I didn't try apostrophes. It worked when I wrap the variable in double quotes

Comment: Tangentially, that's a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Branch` needs to be quoted as well:

```sh
get_data() {
  cat <<EOF
    {
        "title": "PR title",
        "head": "$Branch",
        "base": "development",
        "body": "PR description"
    }
  EOF
}
```